# How to define implicit Ordering on the key type being a tuple in repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The purpose is to repartition an RDD[((Int, Double), Int)] and sort within each partition according to the second element(i.e. the Double field) in the key. What I try is

```
implicit val ordering: Ordering[(Int, Double)] = Ordering.by(fk => (fk._1, fk._2 * -1))
```

However I get the javaNullPointerException. The following is the

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 27.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 27.0 (TID 2089, x01tbipapp3a): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.math.Ordering$$anonfun$by$1.apply(Ordering.scala:219)
        at scala.math.Ordering$$anonfun$by$1.apply(Ordering.scala:219)
        at scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9.compare(Ordering.scala:200)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedPairCollection$$anon$3.compare(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedPairCollection$$anon$3.compare(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:252)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:110)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Sorter.sort(Sorter.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PartitionedPairBuffer.partitionedDestructiveSortedIterator(PartitionedPairBuffer.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.partitionedIterator(ExternalSorter.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.iterator(ExternalSorter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I did find implicit

```
implicit val ordering: Ordering[(Int, Double)] = Ordering.by(fk => fk._2 * -1)
```

Comment: You don't need to put things into implicit scope, you can also directly pass an `Ordering` object.

Comment: I have other ways to implement the function. But I am just curious to know why it is not working.

Comment: As you can see from the stacktrace, your ordering isn't applied. Otherwise you'd see a single line pointing to your `Ordering` instance.

Comment: @Reactormonk, from the stacktrace, I saw the anonfun of Ordering is called. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it's the anonfun in `Ordering.scala` is called. Not yours.

Comment: How do you call `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`? Did you check if your key-value RDD is with the key type being `(Int, Double)`? "Show me the code".